# sp_send_dbmail with dynamic SQL inside of an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

As this is the first time I have needed write T-SQL for this particular situation, I was hoping someone could review my T-SQL to check for errors.  What have I gotten wrong, and how would I fix it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER SendConfirmationEmail
ON dbo.Appointments
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(PersID)
BEGIN
--Declare and Set Dynamic SQL Variables
DECLARE @MsgBody NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @MsgDate DATE;
DECLARE @MsgTime TIME(0);
DECLARE @MsgSubject VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @MsgRecipients NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @MsgDate = (SELECT [Date] FROM [Appointments] WHERE inserted.PersID = Appointments.PersID)
SELECT @MsgTime = (SELECT [Time] FROM [Appointments] WHERE inserted.PersID = Appointments.PersID)
SET @MsgSubject = 'Appointment Confirmation'
SET @MsgBody = 'You are confirmed for a physical appointment on ' + @MsgDate + ' at ' + @MsgTime + '.'
SELECT @MsgRecipients = (SELECT [p.Email] FROM [Personnel].[dbo].[PData] as p JOIN [Physicals].[Appointments] AS ph ON p.PersID = ph.PersID WHERE inserted.PersID = Appointments.PersID)
--Execute the SP to send the confirmation e-mail
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail_Profile', @recipients = @MsgRecipients, @subject = @MsgSubject, @body = @MsgBody
```

When I try to save the trigger I get the following error:

The multi-part identifier 'inserted.PersID' could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier 'inserted.PersID' could not be bound.
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Clearly it does not like to use the trigger virtual "inserted" table inside that select statement setting that variable.  How would this be done correctly?  Basically, I just want to retrieve a corresponding value from a different table than the one the trigger is happening on, and use it in the trigger on this table.  More simply, when the PersID value is updated, I want to get information about that from a different table and then send a confirmation e-mail.

SOLUTION: @Tobsey was incredibly helpful, for anyone else who has this problem I have included the final incarnation of the code that passes SSMS validation.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SendConfirmationEmail] 
ON [dbo].[Appointments]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(PersID)
BEGIN
--Declare and Set Dynamic SQL Variables
DECLARE @MsgBody NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @MsgDate DATE;
DECLARE @MsgTime TIME(0);
DECLARE @MsgSubject VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @MsgRecipients NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @MsgDate = (SELECT ph.Date FROM [Physicals].[dbo].[Appointments] AS ph INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = ph.PersID WHERE inserted.PersID = ph.PersID)
SELECT @MsgTime = (SELECT ph.Time FROM [Physicals].[dbo].[Appointments] AS ph INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = ph.PersID WHERE inserted.PersID = ph.PersID)
SET @MsgSubject = 'Appointment Confirmation'
SET @MsgBody = 'You are confirmed for a physical appointment on ' + CAST(@MsgDate AS varchar) + ' at ' + CAST(@MsgTime AS varchar) + '.'
SELECT @MsgRecipients = (SELECT p.Email FROM [Personnel].[dbo].[PData] as p INNER JOIN [Physicals].[dbo].[Appointments] AS ph ON p.PersID = ph.PersID INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = ph.PersID WHERE inserted.PersID = ph.PersID)
--Execute the SP to send the confirmation e-mail
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail_Profile', @recipients = @MsgRecipients, @subject = @MsgSubject, @body = @MsgBody
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on the Inserted table as well. You can't just use it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT @MsgDate = 
    (SELECT [Date] FROM 
    [Appointments] 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = Appointments.PersID)

SELECT @MsgTime = 
    (SELECT [Time] FROM 
    [Appointments] 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = Appointments.PersID)

SELECT @MsgRecipients = 
    (SELECT [p.Email] FROM 
    [Personnel].[dbo].[PData] as p 
    INNER JOIN [Physicals].[Appointments] AS ph ON p.PersID = ph.PersID 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON inserted.PersID = ph.PersID)
```

You will also need to cast your `date`and `time` types to `varchar` in order to concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tobsey.  One quick question: When you said that I need to cast my `date` and `time` types to `varchar`, I was looking at [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) and noticed that there it calls this an Implicit conversion and states that CAST is not required here.  Are you referring to an exception to this rule, or is someting different happening here?